# Syntax error in triple join query

Tags: sql, postgresql

On Postgresql 9.3, running the following query:

```
select p.name 
from products p 
   join categories c on c.id = p.category_id 
   join descriptions d on d.product_id = p.id 
where p.name LIKE 'word' 
   or c.name LIKE 'word' 
   or d.body LIKE 'word'
```

Fails with:

> syntax error at or near "descriptions"

Product, category, and descriptions are standard table-backed rails models where a product has one category and many descriptions.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why `LIKE` without a wildcard,use directly `=`

Comment: The query is fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/078dd/1 maybe some error when you build it dynamically? E.g. a missing whitespace when you concatenate the SQL string or something similar.

Comment: @Mihai I am not using like but %, I added like to simplify the problem since people could thnk its a pg_trgm issue.

Comment: Most probable cause is that there are some non-ascii characters hidden in the query somewhere. (BOM?) Try retyping it.

Comment: @wildplasser retyping worked! :D

Comment: How on earth can I find it on my own when this pops up again? Also, can you post your answer so that I can mark it the correct one?

Comment: Normally with this kind of spooky bugs I hexdump the .sql file and check it for non-ascii.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a syntax error in this query:

```
select p.name
from products p join
     categories c
     on c.id = p.category_id join
     descriptions d
     on d.product_id = p.id
where p.name LIKE 'word' or c.name LIKE 'word' or d.body LIKE 'word';
```

Are you sure you have a table named `descriptions` in the database?

I want to note that this works in [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/27927/1).

You *will* get exactly your error with this query:

```
select p.name
from products p join
     categories c
     on c.id = p.category_idjoin
     descriptions d
     on d.product_id = p.id
where p.name LIKE 'word' or c.name LIKE 'word' or d.body LIKE 'word';
```

I suspect that you have a syntax error like that in your actual query.

Comment: If the table wasn't there, the error message should be different, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, I do have those tables defined.

Comment: It fails in psql for some reason.

Comment: it was an ASCII issue. See comments on my post.